# os.path.join does not put \ in front of the Users folder

Tags: python-3.x

I started making a program that completes the quizlet by itself, however, in order to log in through my google account I have to use firefox.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import os
username = os.getenv('username')
path_for_profile = os.path.join( "C:","Users", username, "AppData", "Roaming", "Mozilla", "Firefox", "Profiles", "sjwriq6x.default")
print(path_for_profile)
url = "https://quizlet.com/latest"
options = Options() 
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path_for_profile)
profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
desired = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=desired, firefox_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(100)
```

```
os.path.join( "C:","Users", username, "AppData", "Roaming", "Mozilla", "Firefox", "Profiles", "sjwriq6x.default")
```

returns

```
C:Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\sjwriq6x.default
```

When it should return

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\sjwriq6x.default
```

What should I do?

Comment: `C:` is not a path, it’s just a drive. `os.path.join` isn’t supposed to be used like that. Do something like `os.path.join('C:\\Users', username, 'AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles')` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that since there is a current directory for each drive,
> `os.path.join("c:", "foo")` represents a path relative to the current
> directory on drive `C:` (`c:foo`), not `c:\foo`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Answer (score 1):

to join a windows path, try for `"c:/sourcedir"`

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:\\', 'sourcedir')
mypath = os.path.join("/", "c:", "sourcedir")
mypath = os.path.join("c:/", "sourcedir")
```

or This may be the best answer:

```
mypath = os.path.join('c:', os.sep, 'sourcedir')
mypath = os.path.join(os.sep, "C:" + os.sep, "sourcedir")
```